# Android setTextSize changes editText height and shape

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, android

Here is my problem:

I want to change the `editText` text size in my java code. I have already defined its height and width. The issue is I want to set the text size in a way that the text appears completely in the `editText` and also its weight and height won't be changed. Here is my `editText` parameters definition and a snapshot of my UI (et[][] is my `editText`s):

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        et[z][0].setText(tmpDate);
        et[z][0].setLayoutParams(params);
        et[z][0].setTextSize(10);
        et[z][0].setWidth(45);
        et[z][0].setHeight(30);

        et[z][1].setText(tmpMoney);
        et[z][1].setLayoutParams(params);
        et[z][1].setWidth(90);
        et[z][1].setHeight(30);//this one is without setTextSize
```

[image]

As you can see, the shape and the margins for first `editText` is changed when I add `setTextSize`

Comment: If edittext height does not change, how can it show all the text? Of course the height of EditText will grow taller when text size becomes bigger.

Comment: @Charlesjean actually as you can see in snapshot, when you set its height it wont grow or shrink anymore. You can see that the numbers in editText are not shown completely right? Also if it would supposed to be changed in height when we changed textSize, then what is the usage of setHeight or setWidth?

Comment: If you want to change the height and width of EidtText, or a TextView, you should set its layoutParameter instead of using setWidth and setHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the padding from the editText (and probably set the gravity property to "center"). If the edittext doesn't has any padding, then you're probably using a nine-patch drawable that you should change (if this is the case I recommend you to create an xml drawable for your edittext's background).
If you need any further help let us now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually the gravity property really works, but I don't get it why I should create an xml to make this problem fixed!

Comment: I don't mean its mandatory. In my experience if you're using a nine-patch the inside drawable boundary overlaps with your text (just like the image when the text crops before getting to the edittext's limit). You can also add the property "lines" or "maxLines" to tell the edittext to be of a specific number of lines (could be 1 to be a single line edittext). Also check the "elipsize" property if you want to add '...' as prefix or suffix.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is not to hard code the width and height of edittext. If edittext is set to fixed height and width it wont allow it to scale when text size is changed resulting in the issue what you are having. All you need to do is set the width and height of edittext to Wrap_Content this will work perfectly and scale your edittext accordingly and as required.

Hope this helps you.
Stll need any help feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want my edit text layout changes based on its text. I mean I don't want to show all the text, because sometimes in my app texts are too long and if I want to show all the texts my whole UI will be a disaster.

Comment: you can set the maxWidhth and maxHeight attribute with wrap_content. that will take ediitext to a limit of size and wont allow it to grow after wards when it has reached that point

Comment: OK, but imagine a table of editText in my app with let's say 4 rows and 4 column, but because of different lengths of texts, each editText has its width and height and of course they are not more than limits. But I think the whole UI would not be well arranged, would it?

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmmm Very True. In this case you will need to keep the size fixed of edittext can i see the UI then i can give u better idea of what to do.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to make it fixed right now, but if I won't succeed I will post the whole UI, and ask for your help definitely. Thanks for your help bro, it means a lot.